# Generate DAL Layer from database (repository pattern)

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3

How to generate DAL layer from already created database, based on repository pattern? Possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, just use the [Visual Studio designers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ff191186) to drag and drop database tables. You might also consider abstracting the operations with your entities behind interfaces in order to weaken the coupling between the consumers of those repositories and the specific implementation.

Comment: Its just generating classes not repository pattern.

Comment: @coure06, that's why I said you need to define interfaces and in the implementation of those interfaces use the auto generated classes. You cannot expect a tool to generate the operations on your models simply because it doesn't know them.

Answer (score 0):

There are several resources on how to abstract the access to your data store using the repository pattern, but so far [this](http://huyrua.wordpress.com/2010/07/13/entity-framework-4-poco-repository-and-specification-pattern/) is the most comprehensive article I've ever seen.

Answer (score 0):

For creating repositories you can use a NuGet package I created, supply a namespace to your models and it will generate Repository and UnitOfWork classes for you based on Entity Framework 6:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/RepositoryGenerator/